# Time War with villians preventing tragedies

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I remember reading a short story which featured a man who was involved in a time war.  He and many others were pulled from major disasters just before their deaths, and brought into the fight.

The enemy had wised up to this, and was preventing these disasters, meaning the 'heroes' of the war had to ensure such things happened 'as scheduled'.

All of this is told to the point-of-view character by a suspected terrorist holding some device.  At the end of the story, he releases the device and disappears.

The story ends with the main character talking about how nothing had happened that day, heading towards the World Trade Center.

Anyone know what the story is?

Comment: Sounds interesting.

Comment: It sounds very interesting.  I'm following it to see if someone knows what this is.

Comment: The essential premise is similar to *Millennium* by John Varley.  Except for the framing device & the 9/11 connection.  *Millennium* was about time travelers from the future kidnapping people who were about to die(ie. just prior to an airplane crash) and transporting them to the future for mysterious(perhaps nefarious) purposes.

Comment: I've read this story, and I know it's not *Millennium*.  *Millennium* was based on the short story *Air Raid*.  I'm certain it was in a collection of short stories about time travel, and was, obviously, written after 2001.  I remember most of the details of the story, and I'm pretty sure it was at the beginning of the collection I read it in, but I don't know the name.  I originally thought it was in *Timegates*, but after reading a summary of the stories, I am mistaken.  I'm going to look for it further tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!  It's the short story [Standing Still](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?865389), collected in the book [Time Twisters](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?89363).  There's a few pages available in preview mode on Google Books, though it skips the climatic reveal.

Comment: Found it on Google Books.  That's exactly right.